# Gmail for Exchange or Microsoft Exchange Active Sync

Tags: email, exchange, samsung-galaxy-a3

We are using Office365 Exchange cloud email accounts.

I have configured Samsung Galaxy A3 and there are 2 email apps by default - GMail and E-mail (probably from Samsung?).

I have added Google account and Exchange account to the phone settings but then could not find the e-mail account in the E-mail app and found it in Gmail app. On the other hand the Gmail account shows only in the E-mail app.

When trying to connect the E-mail app to Office365 account, it creates second Microsoft Exchange Active Sync account that presumably synchronizes independently from GMail Exchange account.

It is quite a messy, what would be the most convenient way for the user to configure those accounts and clients presuming that the user wants to save contacts to Google account and view e-mail & calendar on Office365 account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are options here.  You can remove accounts in Settings - Cloud and Accounts - Accounts (based on S7 Edge running Android 7.0):

1. Currently the way you are doing it
2. Remove all accounts, log into Gmail with your personal Gmail account, open the Mail app and use "Exchange" to connect to your Office 365 account
3. Use Gmail to access your Gmail account, then also add your Office 365 account to view in Gmail app (Gmail app supports Exchange accounts)
4. Use only Mail app to access Gmail and Office 365 accounts
5. Use Gmail and third-party app for Office 365 access (Outlook, Nine for Android, TouchDown, many others)

There's a lot of options here.  It is up to the user how they best organize and use their apps.

Comment: Are *Gmail for Exchange* and *Microsoft Exchange Active Sync* accounts functionally equivalent?

Comment: All I know is Gmail supports Exchange ActiveSync accounts.